# object oriented programming in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, logging

I have a basic question as follows:

I have 2 separate modules main.js and logger.js in the very same directory. the logger.js is simply:

```
function Logger(){
    return this;
};

Logger.prototype.log = function(str) {
    console.log('[' + this.mPrefix + ']' + str);
};

Logger.prototype.init = function(pr){
    this.mPrefix = pr;
}
module.exports = Logger;
```

Now, I want to use my logger in the main module like this:

```
var logger = require('./logger.js');
logger.init('MAIN');

logger.log('foo');
```

But node insists that `Logger` has no method named `init` or `log`. I also tried `require('./logger.js')()`, since I'm passing a function returning self object, but it did not help. What is the best practice for defining objects in other modules and exporting them? By the way, It happens to work by doing this:

```
var logger = require('./logger.js');
var l = new logger();
l.init('MAIN');
l.log('bar');
```

However it seems clumsy to me. Any explanations & suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a constructor; that’s what `prototype` is for. If you want one global logger object, you need to export one global logger object:

```
var logger = {};

logger.log = function(str) {
    console.log('[' + logger.mPrefix + ']' + str);
};

logger.init = function(pr) {
    logger.mPrefix = pr;
};

module.exports = logger;
```

Alternatively, you can export an instance of `Logger`:

```
module.exports = new Logger();
```

Which is a minimal change and will be changed minimally in case you ever do want to expose the constructor.

If you did actually want to create multiple `Logger` instances, you’re stuck with a constructor – but no worries, it’s a good thing. You can replace `init` with the constructor, too.

```
function Logger(pr) {
    this.prefix = pr;
}

Logger.prototype.log = function(message) {
    console.log("[%s] %s", this.prefix, message);
};

module.exports = Logger;
```

and

```
var Logger = require("./logger");
var logger = new Logger("MAIN");
```

Comment: that creates a "static" class and cannot be reused. So mPrefix will be changed whenever init is called. I guess he wants to reuse the logger and log stuff with different prefixes...

Comment: exactly Ela. My aim is to reuse the logger in different modules.

Comment: @px5x2: So what would your ideal syntax be? I’ve added an example of actually using the constructor to do something useful (and it saves a line in your consumer code) but apart from that, `require` caches, and there’s not a lot you can do.

Comment: @Ela "that creates a "static" class and cannot be reused", I do not think so, everytime i "require" logger doesn't it create new Logger object in the first example of minitech's? Separate Logger instances will be created imho by calling `module.exports = new Logger()`.

Comment: @px5x2: No, `require` caches, which is why I said you’ll have a tough time doing it any other way. But why not use a constructor? That’s what it’s for.

Comment: @px5x2 as minitech stated, require does load the file only once and will not create any instances of anything by its own... it just loads the js file and you have to do what you want with it if loaded.
Regarding the static class, the first example from mimitech will be static, he edited his post, the second example is equal to mine, it creates a new instance

Comment: @minitech I guess i will use your approach, I looked at some logger projects at github and have seen usages like yours. I confused about using new op or initializing with a helper method. For example mysql package do not use that approach, although, connections might be different among various modules. If require caches how will that case be handled?

Comment: @px5x2: Most DB libraries use a callback, e.g. `mysql.connect(connectionInfo, function(err, connection) { … });` – but that’s because they’re asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `function Logger() {}` defines the constructor or your object. (You don't want to return `this` from the constructor, by the way.)

And yes, you would have to create an instance of your object to access the functions you defines in the prototype of your object.

To hide a the logger class you could also create a "static" object by doing something like this:

```
var Logger = {};
(function () {
    var logger = function (pr) {
        this.mPrefix = pr;
    };

    logger.prototype.log = function (str) {
        console.log('[' + this.mPrefix + ']' + str);
    };
    Logger.getLogger = function (pr) {
        return new logger(pr);
    };
})();
```

Now you would have to call `Logger.getLogger()` to get a new instance.

And btw. read this to [learn about JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) objects

Comment: And the exports statement will be how?

Comment: module.exports = Logger; I guess, then call Logger.getLogger() to get an instance

Comment: Might have been for the W3Schools link. W3Schools is a bit notorious here (and not in that good way that they’re always talking about on that commercial), as you may or may not know. Can you find a better tutorial somewhere?

Comment: @minitech sure, that was just the first link on google and it had some meaningful content^^ changed it to the mozilla introduction https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript